# Get inner type from concrete type associated with a TypeVar

Tags: python, mypy

I'm using `mypy` and the `typing` module in python. Imagine I have a generic type:

```
ContainerT = TypeVar('ContainerT')

class Thingy(Generic[ContainerT]):
    pass
```

However I want to get at another type inside the concrete type associated with the TypeVar like in the example below:

```
class SomeContainer(object):
    Iterator = SomeCustomIterator

ContainerT = TypeVar('ContainerT')

class Thingy(Generic[ContainerT]):
    def foo(self) -> ContainerT.Iterator:
        pass
```

I get an error saying that `TypeVar` does not have a member `Iterator`. Is there another way to reformulate this so I can associate one type with another?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can have proper associated types, but maybe you can make the iterator another generic type parameter on Thingy and somehow constrain which combinations are valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking about something like this.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Iterator, Protocol

_Iterator = TypeVar('_Iterator', bound=Iterator, covariant=True)

class SomeContainer:
    iterator: Iterator[int]

    def __init__(self, iterator: Iterator[int]):
        self.iterator = iterator

    def get_iterator(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return self.iterator


class SomeContainerProtocol(Protocol[_Iterator]):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, iterator: _Iterator):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_iterator(self) -> _Iterator:
        pass


_SomeContainer = TypeVar('_SomeContainer', bound='SomeContainerProtocol', covariant=True)


class Thingy(Generic[_SomeContainer]):
    container: _SomeContainer

    def __init__(self, container: _SomeContainer):
        self.container = container

    def foo(self: Thingy[SomeContainerProtocol[_Iterator]]) -> _Iterator:
        pass

    def bar(self) -> _SomeContainer:
        pass

thingy = Thingy(SomeContainer(range(10).__iter__()))
reveal_type(thingy) # Revealed type is '...Thingy[...SomeContainer*]'
reveal_type(thingy.foo) # Revealed type is 'def () -> typing.Iterator[builtins.int]'
reveal_type(thingy.bar) # Revealed type is 'def () ->  ...SomeContainer*'
```

You can annotate self with a generic protocol (available starting Python 3.8) in place of your type var and mypy will then infer the type of the iterator.